# discord bot missing a permission to execute a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a kick script that all works fine, and I want to add a section about the bot missing the kick permission therefore it cannot kick the user. I have this code here:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("."))

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : commands.MemberConverter, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{member} has been kicked!",description=f"Reason: {reason}", color=0x00ff00)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions): #User doesn't have kick perms.
        embed=discord.Embed(title="You don't have the permission to kick members!", color=0xff0000)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument): #User didn't include argument.
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Missing Argument!",description="`.kick <user> <reason>` to kick a user.", color=0xff0000)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        raise(error)
```

The answer doesn't need to be in an embed, I can do that myself, but if anyone knows what elif statement I should add about the bot missing the kick permission then please help.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use `discord.Forbidden`

```
elif isinstance(error, discord.Forbidden):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Missing Permissions!",description="I am missing the required permissions to run this command.", color=0xff0000)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: That didn't work:
```discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Comment: i recommend you to use ``on_command_error`` if you use classic context commands(prefix commands)